# Right align vertically centered grid cell?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to center vertically and right align text in a grid cell but

If I use 'text-align: right' it works... (First example)

If I use 'display: flex' and 'align-items: center' it works... (Second example)

If I use them both, 'text-align: right' stops working? (Third example)

How can I right align centered text please and thanks.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px auto;
}

.A {
  background-color: cyan;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.B {
  background-color: cyan;
  text-align: right;
}

.C {
  background-color: cyan;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: right;
}

.D {
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">
    Test.
  </div>
  <div class="D">
    <ul>
      <li>Test.</li>
      <li>Test.</li>
      <li>Test.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div class="container">
  <div class="B">
    Test.
  </div>
  <div class="D">
    <ul>
      <li>Test.</li>
      <li>Test.</li>
      <li>Test.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div class="container">
  <div class="C">
    Test.
  </div>
  <div class="D">
    <ul>
      <li>Test.</li>
      <li>Test.</li>
      <li>Test.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to set `align-items` you need to be `display: flex` so that reason why is working in first one, In third example you don't use `flexbox` so `align-items` not working & `text-align: center` will not work too because if you need to align the text on horizontal you need to use `justify-content` with flexbox, if you need to align it vertically you will need `align-items` with flexbox, so here is your example with right properties

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px auto;
}
.A,
.B,
.C {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
.A {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.B {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.C {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.D {
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`justify-content: flex-end;` is what you need to right align centered text

More info about `justify-content`: [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px auto;
}

.A {
  background-color: cyan;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.B {
  background-color: cyan;
  text-align: right;
}

.C {
  background-color: cyan;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: right;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.D {
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">
    Test.
  </div>
  <div class="D">
    <ul>
      <li>Test.</li>
      <li>Test.</li>
      <li>Test.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div class="container">
  <div class="B">
    Test.
  </div>
  <div class="D">
    <ul>
      <li>Test.</li>
      <li>Test.</li>
      <li>Test.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div class="container">
  <div class="C">
    Test.
  </div>
  <div class="D">
    <ul>
      <li>Test.</li>
      <li>Test.</li>
      <li>Test.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```